# Force saving a lowercase URL in the SilverStripe admin

Tags: silverstripe

For SEO purposes I need to be sure all URLs are saved as lowercase.

How can I force the SilverStripe admin to save the URL in lowercase even if the user types the permalink in uppercase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in your `Page`'s `onBeforeWrite` method:

```
protected function onBeforeWrite() {
    parent::onBeforeWrite(); //this is important!
    $this->URLSegment = strtolower($this->URLSegment);
}
```

See [API docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_onBeforeWrite)

Comment: Thanks works perfect, it have to be added in the:class Page extends SiteTree {} function.

Comment: Of course you can put it in a DataExtension (where you also have the onBeforeWrite() method) if you prefer to have it more modular and portable.

Comment: @wmk how can i contact you?